# Python while inside of for loop

Tags: python

Everything works but when it gets back to the while loop for the second time, it doesn't execute the the "for USER" part again.

`# SEND PASSWORD FROM LIST

                s.send("\r\n")
                # RECIEVE DATA



 Attempts Remaining: 70
1
0
73`

Comment: This looks [familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379825/python-how-to-go-back-to-previous-loop). Are you this other person, or working with this person, or classmates of this person?

Comment: yes we are working together. the code is different from that post but we are still trying to get the same result iwth no luck

Comment: you want to use `sendall` and the `recv`-part looks weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `passwordlist` has value greater than 70 at the beginning. When you check passwords for users, you check whether `passwordlist` is greater then 70. If it's not, while loop executes no iteration. You decrement this value when password fails, but you don't reset it for the next user. Add

`passwordlist = number_of_attempts`

just before executing this while loop (replacing `number_of_attempts` with desired value).

Comment: thanks I think that was a problem, but now the output shows it has reset passwordlist (attempts) to 73 but then it still refuses to try the next user loop... !! thanks for your help. any ideas?>

Answer (score 0):

Your condition for the loop that controls sending passwords is `while passwordlist > 70:` but `passwordlist` is never reset back. The "Attempts remaining" line shows that it is 0, which means that the condition is false and the loop will not repeat.

Comment: yes, i dont want the password loop to repeat, once it is false, I want it to go up and repeat with the next USER. The point is "Try user1 with password a,b,c then when passwords remaining = 0, try user2 with password a,b,c

Comment: @Archer Yes, but when you "go up and repeat with the next USER" you should reset `passwordlist` to whatever its initial value is. Instead, it is still 0 so the password loop is never entered again.